# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int' in while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, nonetype

There is a function to match a string with the items in a list, which returns the index number of an list item if there is a match. Like below:

```
def get_int(get_wd, get_list):
   for i, j in enumerate(get_list):
       if j == get_wd:
         get_i = i
         return get_i
```

And there is a while-loop in the main function to obtain the return integer from above function:

```
get_wd = []
x = 0
candi = []

while len(li_a) > 0:
    iter_a = iter(li_a)
    srh_time = len(li_a)
    while srh_time > 0:
        temp = next(iter_a)
        if temp in li_words:
            candi.append(temp)
        else:
            pass
        srh_time = srh_time - 1
    max_len = max(len(s) for s in candi)
    extr_wd = list(set(s for s in candi if len(s) == max_len))
    pos = get_int(extr_wd, li_a) ##Calling the function##
    get_wd.append(extr_wd)
    li_a = li_a[pos + 1:]
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
>> li_a = li_a[pos + 1:]
>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Any advice for what I'm missing?

Comment: pos isn't equal to anything, your function that you wrote above did not return anything hence the variable you assign it to is `NoneType`. Also you don't need `get_i` in your original function. Just return `i`, `if j == get_wd:`

Comment: I tried that too before but still having the same message. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think get_int is expecting `str` or `int` as the first  `list` as the second argument, but `pos = get_int(extr_wd, li_a)` here both arguments are `list`, you should fix this.

you can use `.index` for finding the index

refactored `get_int` method:

```
def get_int(get_wd, get_list):
     try:
         return get_list.index(get_wd)
     except ValueError:
         return -1 # not found
```